# How do I recruit Nagi?

Tags: recettear-an-item-shops-tale

In *Recettear*, I figure my main interest is in the recruitment of Nagi to my side as soon as I can. I like spears, ain't more to it. I've run into her in a dungeon in the first week or so, which gives me hopes that she isn't some manner of late-game arrival into my party (and thus the character list on the site isn't in order of people joining).

And so it brings the question, **how do I recruit Nagi**? Ideally, by the earliest time possible, as well as any tricks that would help in the process.

Comment: I don't know the specifics, but I know I bumped into her quite a few times, both in dungeons and in the store.  I actually can't recall if she has offered to join me now or not.  My guess is that you need to keep encountering her in dungeons to advance her plot line (since she says different things each time), so the more often you visit dungeons, the faster you'll be able to recruit her.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to bump into her four separate times (I think). All you need to do is talk to her, and after the fourth time (when she finally tells the two her name) she will start to come by the shop.

When she enters your shop for the second time, she will give you her card.

Additionally, she will never be wandering the dungeons before Day 9.

Comment: Are there any restrictions to which dungeons she'll appear in? Can she appear multiple times in one journey?

Comment: @Grace Note - I know she can appear in the Green Way. I would imagine that you can't run into her multiple times in the same adventuring trip, though that is only my gut instinct, rather than something I have seen personally.

Comment: Finally got her by just being persistent in going to the Jade Way and Amber Garden. Never found her more than once per journey, but she can appear in the same dungeon sections that she was last found in.